# How do you join an ordered set with hashes in Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

In Redis, say I have an ordered set of IDs (which are scored by a timestamp):

```
(name of ordered set) someobject:media

Member | Score
1        1442784376400
2        1442784376420
3        1442784376450
```

Each member is an ID of a hash (like this):

```
media:1      { 'name': 'something', 'timestamp': '1442784376400 }
media:2      { 'name': 'somethingelse', 'timestamp': '1442784376420' }
// and so forth
```

Is there an atomic operation that would allow me to get all the hashes for the members of `someobject:media`?

I'm using [Node Redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis), which in theory provides all the operations that redis-cli provides (as one would expect).

So far, my only thought is to loop through everything, like this:

```
client.zrevrange(['someobject:media', 0, -1], (err, res) => {
  let promises = res.map(mediaId => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      client.hgetall('media:' + mediaId, (err, res) => {
        resolve(res);
      });
    });
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
    // do something with the "media" hashes
  });
});
```

My gut tells me there is some sort of atomic "join" type operation that Redis provides, but maybe I'm wrong. The above method looks entirely inefficient.

In other words, I want to join on all `media:<id>` from the ordered set of `someobject:media`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `sort` works with hashes.  You can use `multi` mode and it will still be efficient. Multi is more typical in redis than something like a join. Something like this:

```
client.zrange("members", 0, 100, function (err, replies) {
     var m = client.multi()
     replies.forEach(function(item) {
         m.hgetall(item);
     });
     m.exec(function(err, hashes) {

     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks closer. I wonder, is there a way to use `SCAN` in this type of operation? Like if I want to get all hashes of `media:*`.

Comment: I think you could use zscan if you wanted to process a lot of members in an iterative cursor-based fashion getting a small amount of data each time rather than retrieving large amount of data in each call.

Comment: Actually, `MULTI` is not really what you need here but rather pipelining, but the I believe the end result would be the same in this case.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. The `SORT` solution almost worked, but I couldn't figure out a way to get it to return the actual `score` of the item in the sorted set, just the member key. With this solution, we can get the score from the `zrange` call and parse it manually into the hash items.

Answer (score 1):

My Redis is suuuuper rusty, but I think you want to use the (confusingly-named) [`SORT`](http://redis.io/commands/sort) command for this. Something like:

```
SORT someobject:media BY nosort GET media:*
```

I've not used node_redis but I think this translates to something like this:

```
client.sort([ "someobject:media", "by", "nosort", "get", "media:*" ], (err, res) =>
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks awesome for lists. Do you know if it's possible for sorted sets? I don't see a sorted set command `SORT`.

Comment: The docs say "Returns or stores the elements contained in the list, set or sorted set at `key`." As far as I know there's nothing special you need to do to use it with a sorted set.

Comment: I don't think you can use that to retrieve hashes.  See my answer.

Comment: @Jason you're right. I was looking at the docs, and you can't get the full hash (*but*, you can get a field from the hash, which can be useful sometimes). For example, you can do `sort someobject:media by nosort get media:*->some_field`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one sort command, but you must explicitly specify all hash fields names. For your example, it would be:

```
sort someobject:media get media:*->name get media:*->time
1) "something"
2) "1442784376400"
3) "somethingelse"
4) "1442784376420"
5) (nil)
6) (nil)
```

For easier reading of the answer, you can add `get #` to get the index as well:

```
sort someobject:media get # get media:*->name get media:*->time
1) "1"
2) "something"
3) "1442784376400"
4) "2"
5) "somethingelse"
6) "1442784376420"
7) "3"
8) (nil)
9) (nil)
```